# Guaranteeing that a task is added to push queue only once in GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, task-queue

I want to ensure that a task — especially a task that operates on a single entity — gets added to a push queue at-most-once, till such a time that the previously added task is finished. Then I should be able to add the same task — for the same entity — again.

A simple example is a task that updates entity A. I want to be able to:

1. Add task X to update entity A to a push queue.
2. While task X is in the queue for entity A, all other attempts to add task X for entity A should fail.
3. Once finished, I should once again be able to add task X for entity A.

The simple solution seems to be to use a task name that incorporates both the name of the task X and the unique ID of entity A.

However, I think this approach doesn't satisfy condition 3: task names get "tombstoned" for an uncontrollable period & can't be re-used till then.

From the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/taskqueue/push/creating-tasks#naming_a_task):

> An advantage of assigning your own task names is that named tasks are
>   de-duplicated, which means you can use task names to guarantee* that a
>   task is only added once. De-duplication continues for 9 days after the
>   task is completed or deleted.

Does this mean task names can't be re-used for 9 days?

Comment: why do you need #2?

Comment: So that I don't have unnecessary contention over updating that entity.

Comment: So what do you do with the entity changes for which you cannot enqueue an updating task?

Comment: @DanCornilescu The next time a task runs to update that entity, it will catch the intervening changes (just need to count all the entities that satisfy particular conditions & then store the count in a property).

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, task names can't be re-used for 9 days after they are no longer in the queue. Probably a safety reason to ensure all traces of the previous identically-named tasks are flushed from the entire distributed infra.

You could encode in the task name the current timestamp, rounded to the full second, which would limit your actual write rate to 1/s (which is the max average write rate to the same entity group anyways). If you fail to enqueue the task (because it is already in the queue) you try to enqueue one for the next second (if you don't have some alternate way of triggering another update task). 
But encode the timestamp towards the end of the task name, not the beginning, to avoid the performance implications mentioned in the same doc you referenced.

Comment: Interesting idea re timestamp. In other, somewhat similar use cases I am already using timestamps, but correct to the millisecond...

Answer (score 1):

I have this use case in the past where I need to do lots of small updates to a single entity, but the update does not need to be reflected immediately. I solved it by batching the update in a pull queue and I have cron job run every X mins to pull a number of tasks and do batch update. In my case the cron job simply enqueue a task to a push queue. The task then consume from the pull queue and do transactional update.

Reference doc https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/articles/fast-and-reliable-ranking-in-datastore/

Comment: This is similar to my use case: could need to do lots of updates, but immediacy is not an issue, correctness is more important. Was hoping to avoid pull queues ☺️, but maybe that's the way to go...

Comment: Why do you want to avoid pull queue? :P It's a little bit extra code to set up, but 0 contention and super fast!

Comment: It's basically laziness at having to set up another set of classes to make using pull queues even more convenient :-). The contention part I really like as re-tried transactions waste a lot of time.